# How can I determine if an Android phone is using the data connection for streaming?

Tags: android, streaming

I'm trying to make an Android app where I need to determine what kind of service class is using a phone, meaning, I'd like to know if the data connection is used for streaming, e-mail, chat, downloads, conferencing...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot know that.

If you could, it'd be a privacy violation ... If an arbitrary app could be installed, and know what I'm using my device. If you could get the application protocol type of all network connections, then you could also get the destination of the connections, and their content as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks! 
But is there a way to, at least, "guess" what the user is doing just from how he's using the data? For example, by checking how much data he's downloading or the bit error rate of the connection?

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you absolutely had to do, here's where I'd start.

There is a permission, perhaps the most dangerous of them all, called READ_LOGS. If that permission is set, then you can read the system logs. Find one relating to network access, then parse it through, and try to figure out how the phone is being used. These logs are deleted at reboot, however.

Personally, I wouldn't install that application, however...

Also worth looking at is the [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class, which will give you basic stuff, but not the details that you want.

Comment: that depends on being able to identify every app that does "IM", "streaming", "downloads", etc. by the specific entries they right to the log file, if they log at all (google recommends turning off logging in production). i don't think that's practical.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman: I don't either, but it's at least an approach that might work. It would take considerable effort.